# Killing a specific item without scoreboard in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to kill for example a dragon head (as a "dropped item") only not all items with /kill so I want to know how to specify what type of item I want to kill without using /scoreboard

Comment: "without using /scoreboard" - why do you want to avoid using scoreboard?

Comment: Since the kill command doesn't accept an NBT tag argument, it is not possible to select a particular kind of item entity to kill without using a scoreboard.

Comment: If you find using /scoreboard too complicated, I can make a tutorial explaining exactly what to do.

Comment: it is easy but it stacks and I want it for stuff that only is necessary for it, like complicated stuff, but to kill a single item I must make a scoreboard for it...

Comment: This is another example of a "wirthout using scoreboard" question that Minecraft 1.13 made into a duplicate by removing the need to use the scoreboard when doing the thing efficiently in the first place (see my answer to the possible duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. It just doesn't work. It's like saying you're trying to make a functioning (insert redstone circuit here) without turning it on.

Comment: that makes no sense, there is a way.

Answer (score -2):

If it's an item thrown on the ground, you can use the kill entity command here

```
/kill @e[type="item"]
```

Insert the item ID of the item you are trying to kill in the "item" spot without quotation marks

This will kill all entities with the item id entered so be careful you don't mess something up.

Comment: This does not work; the `type` of all dropped item entities is always `minecraft:item`. You cannot put `stone` or `stick` in there, for example.

Comment: exactly, it doesn't work, check before posting